# Syntax error for calculated column

Tags: calculated-column

I keep getting syntax errors for This calculated column

```
IF(ISBLANK([First Potential Purchasers Selling Price];"0"; TEXT([First Potential Purchasers Selling Price] - [NBV];"0000000,00"))
```

im trying to simulate

```
if(First Potential Purchasers Selling Price == null)
       display 0

       else display (First Potential Purchasers Selling Price - NBV)
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of a closing paren for the ISBLANK (just before the first ";") your formula works, at least in locales where ";" is used in place of ",".

```
=IF(
 ISBLANK( [First Potential Purchasers Selling Price] ) ;
 "0"; 
 TEXT([First Potential Purchasers Selling Price] - [NBV]; "0000000,00")
)
```

elsewhere it would look like this:

```
=IF(
 ISBLANK([First Potential Purchasers Selling Price] ) ,
 "0", 
 TEXT([First Potential Purchasers Selling Price] - [NBV], "0000000.00")
)
```